# Firebase Verify ID token strange behavior

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Implemented verifiedtoken function based on this article:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Getting following error:

> Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

And here is the code:

```
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


module.exports = {

  async create(ctx) {
    let request_body = ctx.request.body;


    var app = await admin.initializeApp({
      credential: {...},
      databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com"
    });


    admin.auth(app).verifyIdToken(request_body.token)
      .then(async function (decodedToken) {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        return uid;
      }).catch(function (error) {

    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only initialize a single `FirebaseApp` instance once per instance. Since Cloud Functions may re-use the container instance, you end up calling `initializeApp` multiple times.

To prevent this, check if the instance is already initialized:

```
var app;
module.exports = {

  async create(ctx) {
    let request_body = ctx.request.body;

    if (!app) {
      app = admin.initializeApp({
        credential: {...},
        databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com"
      });
    }


    return admin.auth(app).verifyIdToken(request_body.token)
      .then(async function (decodedToken) {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        return uid;
      }).catch(function (error) {

      });

  }
};
```

Or alternatively:

```
module.exports = {

  async create(ctx) {
    let request_body = ctx.request.body;

    if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
      admin.initializeApp({
        credential: {...},
        databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com"
      });
    }
    let app = admin.apps[0];

    return admin.auth(app).verifyIdToken(request_body.token)
      .then(async function (decodedToken) {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        return uid;
      }).catch(function (error) {

      });

  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Console.log-ing `uid` gives me correct result. I want to return `uid` back to the parent function and work on it. How to assign kid to a variable inside `create` function and continue to the next lines?